# Sample Pandas dataframe based on values in column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that I want to sample based on values on the `target` column value, which is binary : 0/1

I want to extract equal number of rows that have 0's and 1's in the "target" column. I was thinking of using the pandas sampling function but not sure how to declare the equal number of samples I want from both classes for the dataframe based on the `target` column.

I was thinking of using something like this:

```
df.sample(n=10000, weights='target', random_state=1)
```

Not sure how to edit it to get 10k records with 5k `1's` and 5k `0's` in the `target` column. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can group the data by target and then sample,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.randn(12000), 'target':np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 2, size=12000)})
new_df = df.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=5000)).reset_index(drop = True)

new_df.target.value_counts()

1    5000
0    5000
```

Edit: Use [DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample)

You get similar results using DataFrame.sample

```
new_df = df.groupby('target').sample(n=5000)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [DataFrameGroupBy.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) method as follwing:

```
sample_df = df.groupby("target").sample(n=5000, random_state=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Also found this to be a good method:

```
df['weights'] = np.where(df['target'] == 1, .5, .5)
sample_df = df.sample(frac=.1, random_state=111, weights='weights')
```

Change the value of `frac` depending on the percent of data you want back from the original dataframe.

Comment: For me, this answer doesn't change on my dataset if it's simply `sample_df = df.sample(frac=.1)`. It seems like the target imbalance remains preserved in my data naturally, although it doesn't intuitively make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run a df0.sample(n=5000) and df1.sample(n=5000) and then combine df0 and df1 into a dfsample dataframe.  You can create df0 and df1 by df.filter() with some logic.  If you provide sample data I can help you construct that logic.