# Sample Pandas dataframe based on multiple values in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to even up a dataset for machine learning. [There are great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191448/sample-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values-in-column) for how to sample a dataframe with two values in a column (a binary choice).

In my case I have many values in column `x`. I want an equal number of records in the dataframe where

- `x` is `0` or `not 0`
- or in a more complicated example the value in `x` is `0`, `5` or  `other value`

Examples

```
     x
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    0
4    0
5    9
6   18
7    3
8    5
```

** For the first **
I have 2 rows where `x = 0` and 7 where `x != 0`. The result should balance this up and be 4 rows: the two with `x = 0` and 2 where `x != 0` (randomly selected). Preserving the same index for the sake of illustration

```
1    5
3    0
4    0
6   18
```

** For the second **
I have 2 rows where `x = 0`, 4 rows where `x = 5` and 3 rows where `x != 0 && x != 5`. The result should balance this up and be 6 rows in total: two for each condition. Preserving the same index for the sake of illustration

```
1    5
3    0
4    0
5    9
6   18
8    5
```

I've done examples with 2 conditions & 3 conditions. A solution that generalises to more would be good. It is better if it detects the minimum number of rows (for `0` in this example) so I don't need to work this out first before writing the condition.

How do I do this with pandas? Can I pass a custom function to `.groupby()` to do this?

Comment: Of course. Update inbound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, and you want *any* two non-zero records:

```
mask = df['x'].eq(0)
pd.concat([df[mask], df[~mask].sample(mask.sum())]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
   x
1  5
2  5
3  0
4  0
```

Part II:

```
mask0 = df['x'].eq(0)
mask5 = df['x'].eq(5)
pd.concat([df[mask0], 
           df[mask5].sample(mask0.sum()), 
           df[~(mask0 | mask5)].sample(mask0.sum())]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
    x
2   5
3   0
4   0
6  18
7   3
8   5
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question just as you pressed submit with a second example!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could `groupby` on the condition whether "x" is 0 or not and `sample` the smallest-group-size number of entries from each group:

```
g = df.groupby(df['x']==0)['x']
out = g.sample(n=g.count().min()).sort_index()
```

(An example) output:

```
1    5
3    0
4    0
5    9
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

---

For the second case, we could use `numpy.select` and `numpy.unique` to get the groups (the rest are essentially the same as above):

```
import numpy as np
groups = np.select([df['x']==0, df['x']==5], [1,2], 3)
g = df.groupby(groups)['x']
out = g.sample(n=np.unique(groups, return_counts=True)[1].min()).sort_index()
```

An example output:

```
2    5
3    0
4    0
5    9
7    3
8    5
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, I added a second example to the question to help understand the other example